# How do I kill the process holding the apt lock?

Tags: apt, kill, ps, lock

I tried doing

```
sudo apt update
```

but got:

> Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
>
> E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/

I am trying to get the latest version of mongod. Following some instructions I found, I did:

```
$ ps aux | grep apt
5019  0.0  0.0  14224   980 pts/0    S+   02:52   0:00 grep --color=auto apt
```

But I don't know which part of this I should plug into

```
kill -9 processnumber <id>
```

to make it work.

Which part is the ID and is there any way to prevent this from happening again?

Comment: The first number is the PID.

Comment: You should try first `kill -TERM 5019` and only later `kill -KILL 5019` (which is the same as `kill -9 5019`, see [kill(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/kill.1.html)....). Read [signal(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html) first.

Comment: You also want to run `lsof /var/lib/apt/lists/lock` to understand who is locking that. See [lsof(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsof.8.html)

Comment: Actually, what xe should try _first_ is _not using the `kill` command at all_, and instead looking at what other instances of the package tool xe happens to be running elsewhere, and simply exiting them in the normal way.

Comment: Note further that the pid that resulted was for grep; killing that pid will at best do nothing and at worst kill something completely unrelated.

Comment: icewizard, can you clarify your question: are you wanting to fix the "apt update" lock issue, or do you want to find a PID to kill? (I would vote for the former, and warn you about the latter -- as per Basile and JdeBP's comments above)

Answer (score 10):

If you want to kill processes based on their name or argument list, use `pkill`.

```
pkill regexp
```

Will kill all processes whose name matches the `regexp` extended regular expression.

```
pkill -f regexp
```

Will kill all processes whose list of arguments (including the first which usually contains the command name) concatenated with spaces matches the regexp.

Here however, it looks more like you want to kill the process(es) that holds the `/var/lib/apt/lists/lock` lock file, so:

```
fuser -k /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
```

(with some fuser implementations) or

```
lsof -t /var/lib/apt/lists/lock | xargs kill
```

may be more appropriate.

Though you may want to check what process it is  first with `lsof /var/lib/apt/lists/lock` or `fuser /var/lib/apt/lists/lock`. And exit it normally if possible instead of coldly kill it.

In any case, avoid `kill -9` which doesn't let a chance to the process to exit cleanly.

Comment: For me, running `lsof /var/lib/apt/lists/lock` gives me nothing. Closing the terminal and reopening worked though.

Answer (score 6):

This illustrates two reasons why you shouldn't use `ps … | grep …`.

`ps` prints a title line. But since the output is piped into `grep`, and the grep pattern doesn't match the title line, you don't get to see the title line. In the title line, you'd see a column called `PID`. The value in this column is what you need to pass to `kill`.

When you run `ps … | grep …`, this often lists the grep process itself. In your case, you're only seeing the grep process. Whether you see the grep process or not is random: the pipe runs `ps` and `grep` in parallel, and often `grep` has had time to start by the time `ps` runs, but sometimes `ps` runs very quickly and `grep` hasn't started yet. There are tricks to avoid seeing the grep process, such as ensuring that the pattern doesn't match itself:

```
ps aux | grep '[a]pt'
```

But there are more reliable ways to do this. Linux and other systems provide a utility called [`pgrep`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html). It works a bit like `ps … | grep …` but more reliably.

```
pgrep apt
```

To get information about the processes, you can pass the process IDs to `ps`:

```
ps $(pgrep apt)
```

If you want to kill them all, you can change the `pgrep` command to `pkill`. If you only want to kill some of them, either add more criteria to the `pgrep` command line so that it only matches the processes you want, or manually select PIDs from the `ps` output.

Linux's `ps` command can also match processes by several criteria, including the command name, but you need an exact match whereas `pgrep` can find substrings and more generally regular expression matches.

```
ps -C apt     # won't find e.g. apt-get
```

None of this is the best way to solve your apt lock problem though. See [Stéphane Chazelas's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/390483) for this.